# Babel transform-async-to-module-method to Bluebird with ES6 maps

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, bluebird

We're trying to use Node.js 6.5.0 with `Babel` to make `async functions` use `Bluebird` instead of native V8 ES6 promises:

Our `package.json` contains only the following `Babel` entries:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-cli": "^6.9.0",
  "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-module-method": "^6.8.0",
  "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.9.0",
  "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.14.0",
}
```

and `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
    "transform-es2015-destructuring",
    [
      "transform-async-to-module-method",
      {
        "module": "bluebird",
        "method": "coroutine"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

However our `async functions` returning ES6 map cause the following error during execution:

> A value [object Map] was yielded that could not be treated as a promise

How do we fix this?

P.S. All worked fine when `async functions` were transformed to `generators` with `transform-async-to-generator`

Answer (score 2):

Here's some sample code that triggers the same error:

```
function giveMap() {
  return new Map();
}

void async function() {
  await giveMap();
}();
```

Notice that `giveMap` isn't marked `async` (which is the actual problem).

This code will run when using `transform-async-to-generator`, because `Map`'s are yieldable from generators:

```
function* () {
  yield new Map();
}
```

However, when using `transform-async-to-module-method`, I think the code becomes similar to this:

```
Promise.coroutine(function* () {
  yield new Map();
});
```

This will cause the error, [as explained here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/error-explanations.html#error-a-value-was-yielded-that-could-not-be-treated-as-a-promise), because `Promise.coroutine()` expects promises to be yielded.

So you should be on the lookout for functions that return a `Map`, are `await`'ed on, but aren't mapped `async`.

Comment: Thanks.  Makes perfect sense. We'll investigate and let you know.